# Can an EXISTS clause be improved when the condition is checked for the same value multiple times?

Tags: sql-server, performance

Assume that I'm modelling a Blog engine. **Blogs** have `n` **Posts**. Each **User** can be granted a role on different **Blogs** (`Admin`, `Approver` or `Editor` stored as enums/ints). Each **Post** can have a **State** (`Draft`, `PendingApproval`, `Published` stored as enums/ints). Here's how it's modeled:

```
Blogs
-----
Id (PK, int, not-null)
Name (varchar, not-null)

Users
-----
Id (PK, int, not-null)
Name (varchar, not-null)

Posts
-----
Id (PK, int, not-null)
BlogId (FK, int, not-null)
State (int, not-null)
Title (varchar, not-null)
Body (varchar, not-null)
(and there is an index on (BlogId, State))

UserBlogRoles
-------------
Id (PK, int, not-null)
UserId (FK, int, not-null)
BlogId (FK, int, not-null)
Role (int, not-null)
(and there is a unique index on (UserId, BlogId))
```

And here are the enums:

```
UserBlogRole
------------
Editor = 0
Approver = 1
Admin = 2

PostState
---------
Draft = 0
PendingApproval = 1
Published = 2
```

As an `Approver`, I want to view a list of all Posts that have the `State = PendingApproval` for all blogs that I have at least the `Approver` role.

Here's the query:

```sql
declare @approverRole int = 1;
declare @pendingApprovalState int = 1;
declare @myUserId int = 12345;

select
    p.Id, p.BlogId, p.State,  p.Title, p.Body
from Posts as p
where 
    p.State = @pendingApprovalState and
    exists (
        select r.Id 
        from UserBlogRoles as r
        where r.Role >= @approverRole and r.BlogId = p.BlogId and r.UserId = @myUserId
    )
```

This works as expected. But, I've been wondering about the performance of the `exists()`. If the same values are passed to the `exists()` multiple times, is it cached? For example, there could be many pending approval posts for a particular blog. Will it need to check the permissions for *each* of those posts and their associated blogs?

I've been thinking of changing it to a `where in (query)` instead:

```sql
select
    p.Id, p.BlogId, p.State,  p.Title, p.Body
from Posts as p
where 
    p.State = @pendingApprovalState and
    p.BlogId in (
        select r.BlogId 
        from UserBlogRoles as r
        where r.Role >= @approverRole and r.UserId = @myUserId
    )
```

But I'm not sure if that'd be better or worse performance? Does SqlServer execute the "in" query once and then use those values to check against the `BlogId`?

I guess this could be changed into a join too.

The execution plans of both showed the same (50% index scan on Posts PK and 50% index scan on UserBlogRoles PK) I think because my sample database doesn't have any data in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exists and IN will give the same query plan because they are both "LEFT SEMI JOINs" internally. I prefer EXISTS generally because of consistency. NOT EXISTS is safer then NOT IN.

Caching does not apply and don't think about it. This is a set based operation and the SQL Server optimiser will work out the best way: It may spool the subquery or it may not. Note that a left semi join is typically very efficient. Don't overthink it.

Finally, a PK scan indicates a missing index on UserBlogRoles

Observation: use the the schema, Luke. `dbo.UserBlogRoles` for example

Comment: I don't know that IN will *always* give the same query plan; I seem to recall multiple scenarios where this wasn't the case (might have been on older versions of SQL Server). As for schema prefix, yup. See [this](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-semi-colons-schema-prefix/) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: At the end of http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/  But I'd avoid predicate functions or calculations anyway...

Comment: I need to do some more testing - I was fairly confident I had proven that there are some cases where `EXISTS` will generate a better plan than `IN` and/or produce more favorable runtime. I still prefer it for consistency and also that it is more flexible (e.g. covers comparison involving more than one column). Also [about `NOT EXISTS` vs. `NOT IN`...](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

Answer (score 3):

On principle, I would always use `EXISTS` rather than `IN`.

1. `EXISTS` has the *opportunity* to short circuit, though it won't always.
2. `IN` has the *opportunity* to be optimized as an `EXISTS`, though it won't always.

So, since `EXISTS` can never be *worse* than an equivalent `IN`, but can sometimes be better...

Comment: When you say short circuit, is it this: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/short-circuit ? (Not heard the term before)

Comment: @Reaces Yes, in some cases `EXISTS` can return as soon as it hits the first row that matches, and stop searching for more rows. This is why `EXISTS` makes more sense than `COUNT` when you are [just ensuring that there is at least one row](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way) (though the optimizer has become smarter about some of those scenarios, too).